# Como ejecutar archivos y cerrarlos (.exe) con python

Tags: python, bucles, callback, proceso, procesos-en-segundo-plano

estoy ejecutando dos archivos .exe, desde python usando popen, todo muy bien para realizar este procedimiento, pero aun no me queda del todo claro como hacer para cerrar dichos programas
Lo que busco es que ambos programas abran al mismo tiempo y cuando termine el programa ("Bot") se cierren los dos
luego de una pausa definida con time.sleep() se vuelvan a ejecutar y asi suceda hasta el momento que yo decida terminar todo

import subprocess

import time

print("Ejecutando")

Vpn = subprocess.Popen(["C:/Users/alexandra/AppData/Local/PenguinProxy/app-0.3.1/PenguinProxy.exe"])

time.sleep(4)

bot_lkd = subprocess.Popen(["C:/Users/alexandra/Downloads/Desktop/ bot/dist/Lkd.exe"])

Comment: Si Lkd.exe no se cierra cuando termina o no informa vía stdout/stderr de que ha terminado de alguna forma, es imposible para el proceso padre determinar cuando a terminado de hacer lo que debe, porque el proceso no ha terminado, solo una tarea que debe hacer. Deberias comprobar si el ejecutable muestra algunaa salida por stdout/stderror que pueda determinar cunado terminó, si existe algo así, entonces el problema no tiene una solución muy complicada.

Comment: Vale amigo, me he puesto a leer un poco mas y si lkd.exe, me muestra stdout la forma como termino, Ahora como podria yo indicarle al programa padre que cuando lkd.exe, se cierre, cierre el Vpn.. Ademas de volver generar un bucle para que sigan ejecutandose